# how can I delete opencv from my bootable SD card

Tags: 14.04, sd-card

I had created a bootable SD card , ubuntu 14.04 image with display, I have downloaded opencv 3.0.0 and opencv 2.4.9 packages and maybe install one of them, now I want to remove all opencv related libraries, I need memory space, I tried `sudo make install` and then `sudo make uninstall` , memory space is still the same, how can I delete all files downloaded in the last 15 days for example :), is there linux instruction to do that..

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove --purge opencv`?

Comment: it return no package named opencv but I return to the old packages and use sudo apt-get remove --purge instead of sudo apt-get install

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Linux find command. So, to find all OpenCV libraries you can do the following (this might take a while)

```
sudo find / -name "*opencv*" -exec rm -i {} \;
```

The above command will find any file containing opencv in the name, and will prompt you to remove it. As always, be careful when deleting things manually!

Reference [here](https://isrishblog.wordpress.com/2012/11/24/how-to-uninstall-opencv-on-ubuntu/)

Comment: That will take a hell of long time.

Answer (score 0):

You can also uninstall by going to the "build" folder directory of opencv from terminal, and execute the following

```
 make uninstall
 cd ..
 sudo rm -r build
 sudo rm -r /usr/local/include/opencv2 /usr/local/include/opencv /usr/include/opencv /usr/include/opencv2 /usr/local/share/opencv /usr/local/share/OpenCV /usr/share/opencv /usr/share/OpenCV /usr/local/bin/opencv* /usr/local/lib/libopencv*
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this a live-media with persistence USB?  According to http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1936331 comment 7, persistence files don't really free up space with deletes (but casper-rw partitions should).  The other advantage of using an ext2 or ext4 (without journaling) partition is that it is not limited to 4G, like the casper-rw files are.